# Opening File Explorer with a path to a shared folder doesn't work

Tags: c#

I have a WPF app in which a file is selected, operated on, and then saved to the same directory under a new name. Pretty standard stuff and all of that operates as expected.

There are buttons on the UI which gives the user the option to either open the file with the default application for its filetype specified in the OS or to open the directory of the file in File Explorer. However, when the specified file path is in a shared folder, both of the buttons open File Explorer to its default location which is the Documents folder. The modified file is still able to be saved to the shared folder though.

This is how File Explorer is opened in the code:

```
ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
{
     Arguments = vm.OutputPath,
     FileName = "explorer.exe"
};
Process.Start(startInfo);
```

I suspect this issue has something to do with the fact that the shared folder is only defined at the user level and is unable to be found when opening File Explorer with Process.Start(...)

Is there anything I can do in the code to correct this?

Comment: `the shared folder is only defined at the user level` there's no such thing. Shared folders are created on file servers and are the same for all users, both local and remote.

Comment: What does `vm.OutputPath` look like?

Comment: @JimRhodes Something like "C:\Users\{user}\OneDrive\SharedFolder\..."

Comment: First, are you sure the share folder path is correct? What you describe happens if the path is wrong. [This page](https://ss64.com/nt/explorer.html) shows the arguments you can use with `explorer.exe`, including examples that show how to open with a shared folder as the root and even how to select a file

Comment: @JackRentz-Essentium that's not a shared folder at all. That's a local folder. It may be OneDrive's local folder but it's still a local folder

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos, no it's definitely a shared folder and the path is correct. The file being modified by the app is still saved there and updates on SharePoint, but it won't open in File Explorer. Thank you for the link though, I think that may be what I'm looking for.

Comment: It's definitely *not* a shared folder, at least what everyone understands as a Windows Shared Folder. That's not an opinion. Shared folders are folders on remote machines that are accessible through the machine name eg `\\thatmachine\somefolder`. If Explorer can't open a *local* folder it's because either the path is wrong or the user has no permission to open the folder. If the path contains spaces, you need to surround it with double quotes. You can try this from the command line or the Run window. Try `explore "c:\Users\....."`

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Ok now I feel dumb. It was absolutely because there were spaces in the path. Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue has been solved thanks to Panagiotis Kanavos' comment on my question. I was dumb and didn't consider the fact that the path could contain spaces and thus needs to be surrounded in double quotes for explorer.exe to accept it.